# How to create custom abbreviations in SQL?

Tags: sql, database

Is it possible to "reuse" sql parameter in an sql `SELECT` statement?

Similar to this pseudocode:

```
<DEFINE> city as c, destination as d
SELECT c, d FROM thetable t INNER JOIN(SELECT c FROM...) etc
```

(so that each parameter has to only be written explicit a single time)?

Comment: Each DBMS has a subtly different way to handle this, which are you using?  probably you're going to need to build your sql dynamically however and execute it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most databases support common table expressions, but you express this as:

```
with t as (
      select city as c, destination as d
      from thetable
     )
select c, d
from t;
```

This may not do what you are asking for.  A common table expression is really a subquery, and within the subquery you can use shorter names.  However, it will not affect column names *across* tables, unless you include more CTEs.

Also, CTEs can have performance implications in some databases. Some databases actually materialize them, creating intermediate tables, and that can affect performance.  Other databases optimize them in place.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to use [common table expressions](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/static/queries-with.html) in postgres. As far as I know it is not possible in mysql for instance. Different database management systems may differ in its compatibility with sql standard.